# Redirecting user if PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I want to enable people to login and deny access to particular states depending on the permissions set in the firebase rules which I have achieved successfully.

I want to avoid the "page flash" redirection.

I have followed the "Auth" state redirection code but I cannot pick up the PERMISSION_DENIED code in the object left by "return $firebaseObject(ref2);"

```
myapp.factory("Auth", function($firebaseAuth) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/");
  return $firebaseAuth(ref);
});


//myedit, got rid of this factory
///myapp.factory("notLive", function($firebaseObject) {
///  var ref2 = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/events");
///  return $firebaseObject(ref2);
///});


// for ui-router
myapp.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
                $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error, code) {
                if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
                    $state.go("home");
                }

                    console.log(code); // returns undefined :(
                ///myedit - changed this
                ///if (code === "PERMISSION_DENIED") { 
                if (error.code === "PERMISSION_DENIED") { 
                    $state.go("home");
                }
            });
}]);
```

This is my state  showing the resolve

```
.state("events", {
    url: "/events",
    templateUrl: "tpl/events.html",
    controller: "eventsCtrl",
    resolve: {
        currentAuth: function(Auth) {
            console.log(Auth.$requireAuth());
            return Auth.$requireAuth();
        },
        ///myedit - changed this
        ///notLive: function(notLive) {
        ///   console.log(notLive.$loaded());
        ///    return notLive.$loaded();
        ///}

        notLive: function($firebaseObject) {
            var refEvents = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/events");
            return $firebaseObject(refEvents).$loaded();
        }
    }
})
```

When my user is denied from the "events" node, they can't see the data which is great, but I would like them to redirect to the home state and maintain a logged in state.

I placed a hack redirect in the "eventsCtrl" but it flashes before being redirected to the "home" state which is not what I want.

MYEDIT - I placed this at the top of the eventsCtrl

```
        var refPermissionDeniedEvents = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/events");
        refPermissionDeniedEvents.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        }, function(err){
            $state.go("home", {}, { reload: true });
        });
```

After doing this, it enables a user to login and be authenticated and sit on the home page, the are denied access to the events page unless I change their permissions in the USERS node and on the permission rules are set on the EVENTS NODE.

After doing this, I have achieved what I need.

Comment: I changed a few things and managed to get it to work, see myedit

Answer (score 1):

You can "decorate" angular routeProvider this way:

```
(function (angular) {
  "use strict";

  var securedRoutes = [];

  angular.module('myApp.security', ['ngRoute', 'Auth', 'myApp.config'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

      $routeProvider.whenAuthenticated = function (path, route) {

        securedRoutes.push(path); // store all secured routes for use with authRequired() below
        route.resolve = route.resolve || {};

        route.resolve.user = ['Auth', function (Auth) {
          return Auth.$requireAuth(); //fetch auth info
        }];

        $routeProvider.when(path, route);
        return this;

      };

    }])

  /**
   * Apply some route security. Any route's resolve method can reject the promise with
   * { authRequired: true } to force a redirect. This method enforces that and also watches
   * for changes in auth status which might require us to navigate away from a path
   * that we can no longer view.
   */
    .run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', 'loginRedirectPath',

      function ($rootScope, $location, Auth, loginRedirectPath) {
        // watch for login status changes and redirect if appropriate
        Auth.$onAuth(check);

        // some of our routes may reject resolve promises with the special {authRequired: true} error
        // this redirects to the login page whenever that is encountered
        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (e, next, prev, err) {
          if (err === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
            $location.path(loginRedirectPath);
          }
        });

        function check(user) {
          if (!user && authRequired($location.path())) {
            //console.log('check failed', user, $location.path()); //debug
            $location.path(loginRedirectPath);
          } 
        }

        function authRequired(path) {
          return securedRoutes.indexOf(path) !== -1;
        }
      }
    ]);

})(angular);
```

where you set `loginRedirectPath` as default path (login page or something) to redirect if user is not authenticated

This is intended to check if user is authenticated only, but you can do additional checks (for permissions etc.) in `function check(user)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "code" is valid.  Didn't see it here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki in the $stateChangeError  section.

Edit:  Not positive, but you probably need to be grabbing the PERMISSION_DENIED error in a catch statement.

```
$loaded().then(function(){}).catch(function(error){console.log(error)})
```

Comment: I did try "error" and it return the "auth" error and not the "permission_denied" error

Comment: see comment.  have you tried catching the the PERMISSION_DENIED similar to that?